# How to understand the `replace` and `update` of some resources in terraform plan output

Tags: terraform

when i do terraform plan, the plan shows some resource needs to be replaced and some needs to be updated.

I doesnot very sure about what `replace` means. does it mean the resource will be destoryed and re-created? what's is the difference between `update` and `replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it mean the resource will be destoryed and re-created?

Yes. Depends on the resource, such replacement can be catastrophic, e.g. replacing a database will lead to full data lose if there are no backups.

> what's is the difference between update and replace?

update will not full replace/destroy the resource.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: some resources are able to be updated **in place** this is what is meant by **updated**. Replace means the resource will be **destroyed and then recreated** as necessary.